# Django admin page written text is not displaying on web page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

Ignore the title. I got problem on displaying text written and save on admin page.
I just create new app with name about. using command python manage.py startapp about
and all the below files are inside this app.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class About(models.Model):
    title = "About me"
    discription = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import About
    # Register your models here.
    admin.site.register(About)
    # Register your models here
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
from .models import About
# Create your views here.
def about(request):
    abouts = About.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'about/about.html', {'abouts': abouts})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'about'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

about.html

```
 <p style="color: white;">{{ abouts.discription }}</p>
```

Problem is that the text written inside discription didn't showing on about.html page. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ abouts }}` is a queryset. The following code iterates over each item inside the queryset, thus creating a list.

```
    <ul>
        {% for about in abouts %}
            <li>{{ about.description }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```